# CSS: Automatic changing color of a specific character?

Tags: css

I am writing a blogger which is about programming.
I want it to automatically change a color of specific character without manually put a class or id into it. For example,

```
 <blockquote class="tr_bq">
 <span style="color: #bb60d5;">$</span>
 <span>php app/console doctrine:schema:create</span>
 </blockquote>
```

When I put the `"$"` character inside the `blockquote tag`, It would automatically add `color: #bb60d5` to change its color.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: CSS by itself probably can't, but Javascript could...

Comment: As someone who wants to automagically make all checkmarks green and ballot-Xs red on a given webpage, I can confidently say I found this question helpful. +1, good sir.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to do this using CSS, you can however use javascript to scan the page on load and wrap all instances of `$` in a span with your custom style, here's an implementation using jQuery:

```
$('blockquote').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(\$)/g, '<span style="color: #bb60d5;">$1</span>'));
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/rjzdL/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

CSS can't find words or something related to that and it can't automatically just add colors or apply styles.

You might use JavaScript, or you can use some server side coding to find out this word '$' and apply some style to that div. For example:

```
<div style="color: red;">
 $<span style="color: black">php app/console doctrine:schema:create</span>
</div>
```

This will work when you know that the server will read the files, in ASP you can use `string.Split()` to find out some parts. You can use Regex, for PHP, you might need to search!

But it won't work in CSS, its just JavaScript or Server Side. You can use CSS to just apply colors, or just use `style` in each element itself.

Answer (score -1):

I know your questions is about CSS, but jQuery maybe the right tool for it. You may have a look into it.

```
if( $("blockquote").children("span:contains('$')").length ){
    $("blockquote span:nth-child(1)").css("color", "#bb60d5");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NicHope/9de7k/#base

Comment: The whole point of the question is to apply the style dynamically to any element that contains `$`

Comment: @koala_dev my script you can use in combination with any triggered event and then it is dynamic. The :containts() will filter by $ and reduces the collection to the matches. Inside the if condition you can excute any code.

Comment: The thing is you don't know if you'll find `$` as the first child